# how to open download window using vimperator in firefox

Tags: firefox, vimperator

How to open download window using vimperator in firefox. Is there any **key map** to view current downloads?

Comment: Are you looking for a key that is equivalent to the :download command?  I don't think there is a key mapping for that by default, but you can add your own key mappings using the :map command.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the command :downloads

Comment: This seems to be broken in both my Linux and OSX envs. (29.01UX for osx and 26 in Linux)

Comment: why? do you experience the 'keys not getting to vimperator' "bug"?

Comment: No the downloads, list is blank, is apparently a known bug in the current release. It is also this way if I do :dialog downloads as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command `:downloads`, but it is not working right now. This [bug](https://code.google.com/p/vimperator-labs/issues/detail?id=952) will be fixed in the next version of Vimperator (current version is 3.8.1).

In the meantime you can add the following to your `.vimperatorrc` (which, basically, does exactly the same as the patch applied to the official Vimperator tree)):

```
js <<EOF
    commands._exCommands = commands._exCommands.filter(function (cmd) !cmd.hasName("downloads"));
    commands.add(["downl[oads]", "dl"],
        "Show progress of current downloads (fixed)",
        function () {
            liberator.open("chrome://browser/content/downloads/contentAreaDownloadsView.xul",
                { from: "downloads"});
        },
        { argCount: "0" },
        true);
EOF
```

(don't forget to restart Firefox or `source ~/.vimperatorrc`)